# Six red dots over my logging PHP app JSON response generates SyntaxError JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, authentication

I have tried modifying mbstring (disable too), use the notepad++ to save it with "UTF-8 without BOM", clean the budffer "ob_clean()" and nothing change. :(

That 's my PHP code:

```
if($veri[0] == 'TRUE' && $veri[1] == 'TRUE'){
  if(isset($_POST['js']) && $_POST['js'] == 'ajax'){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('login'=>true,'redi'=>true,'url'=>'./?p=publicar'));
    exit();
  }
}
```

And this is my Javascript code :

```
function ajax(){
        this.respuesta;
        this.ajaxCall = function(f, method, url, callback){
            try{
                var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                x.open(method, url);
                x.onreadystatechange =  function(){
                    if(x.status == 200 && x.readyState == 4){
                        this.respuesta = x.responseText;
                        if(x.getResponseHeader('Content-type') == 'text/html'){
                            callback(this.respuesta);
                        }else if(x.getResponseHeader('Content-type') == 'application/json'){
                            this.respuesta = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
                            if(this.respuesta.login == true){
                                window.location = this.respuesta.url;
                                document.removeEventListener('keydown', function(){
                                    if(evt.keyCode == 27){

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        this.respuesta = false;
                    }
                }
                if(method=='GET'){
                    x.send(f);
                }else if(method=='POST'){
                    x.send(f);
                }
            }catch(e){
                pass('Error');
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally this is the error produced. (Firefox) :

[image]

I try many things but i don´t catch the error. Please help me !

*****----- FINALLY I FOUND HOW TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM -----*****
I just needed to copy the code from each php page and then paste it to a new php page with the same php name using dreamweaver or in notepad++, when copied, you need to press the "CONVERT UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM" and then save the file in a complete new folder (just to be sure not to combine with the original folder). And taht´s all.

Comment: what is `exit();` for?

Comment: you have hidden unicode characters, being non-printable.

Comment: exit() is there to stop reading the next code secuence; the next code secuence doesn´t appear because has nothing to do with this.

Comment: you say you tried `ob_clean()` but that's nowhere to be found in what you posted.

Comment: If there is hidden unicode characters, how can i remove them. I just try Notepad++ without BOM and nothing. :(

Comment: ob_clean was used al the top of the PHP page. Beleive me !

Comment: Yes, the red dots are likely non-printable characters you inadvertly output somewhere before the code you showed. And `ob_clean()` has nothing to do with removing them: it clears _the output buffer_, not the already outputted data! You must check your code to find where you output those characters.

Comment: Another situation i already realize is that in my localhost, the same PHP code goes well without dots but, when i upload it to the real server, the six red dots appears. Why is that i don´t understand.

Comment: Finally i found a solution: I just needed to copy the code from each php page and then paste it to a new php page with the same php name using dreamweaver or in notepad++, when copied, you need to press the "CONVERT UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM" and then save the file in a complete new folder (just to be sure not to combine with the original folder). And taht´s all.